# Mysterious excess space in div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay text over an image, and when I wrap an image in a div and apply a border, you can see that there is extra space afterward. Where is this space coming from, and how do I remove it? The following jsfiddle has an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/ngd5R/22/

Notice that the background of `.avatar` is red to show that the bounding box is larger than the image it contains. I can't just apply the border to `img` since `.message` relies on the height of the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your rules for `.avatar img`:

```
display: block;
```

The red background will go away. [Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngd5R/23/). By default, images are *inline* elements (technically, `inline-block` IIRC), meaning that they flow the same as text. If you make the image a block-level item, the "text-style" flow rules won't apply.